# Issues in integrating Google Play Game Services Leaderboard in AndEngine Game

Tags: andengine, google-play-games

I'm trying to store and display the user's game score in a leaderboard using Google Play Game Services . I'm following this --> https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init . The issue arises when I import the BaseGameUtils library in my project , then all the andEngine classes display an error (for eg. Camera cannot be resolved and my imports also display an error) . Also , there are two BaseGameActivity.java classes (one in the andEngine jar and one in the BaseGameUtils library ) . How to resolve this issue , please help .

Comment: implement Your BaseGameActivity code into your mainActivity

Comment: I didn't get what you're trying to say .

Comment: What i mean is copy BaseGameActivity class source code from BaseGameUtils library int your game Activity

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it in following way: 
1. Changed the name of BaseGameActivity (from BaseGameUtils lib) to GoogleBaseGameActivity
2. Made it to extend AndEngine BaseGameActivity
3. In my main game activty I extend GoogleBaseGameActivty instead of Andengine one.

Object oriented programming guys:)

Comment: Smart thinking! I will do the same :)