# GoogleBaseGameActivty extends BaseGameActivty(AndEngine) Crash

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, andengine

Been struggling with andEngine and Google Game services integration for some time now. So I thought i would try my luck here.

I have done the steps described in multiple posts and blogs like this:
[Issues in integrating Google Play Game Services Leaderboard in AndEngine Game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22686201/issues-in-integrating-google-play-game-services-leaderboard-in-andengine-game)

Using android studios and gradle

I have added BaseGameUtils([Android Sample](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples)), and extended the AndEngine BaseGameActivity and renamed GoogleBaseGameActivity. And then I have replaced BaseGameActivtiy with GoogleBaseGameActivity in my GameActivty(mainActivity)

The game runs before I do the extending and renaming.

MainActivity:

```java
public class GameActivity extends GoogleBaseGameActivity
```

BaseGameActivity in BaseGameUtils(Google):

```java
import org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity; 

public abstract class GoogleBaseGameActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements GameHelper.GameHelperListener
```

Logcat:

```
03-23 10:36:15.006  15860-15860/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15860 SIG: 9
03-23 10:51:33.826  17012-17012/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame W/dalvikvm﹕ No implementation found for native Ldalvik/system/VMRuntime;.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
03-23 10:51:33.826  17012-17012/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame E/ActivityThread﹕ Pause GC
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5410)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5410)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-23 10:51:33.831  17012-17012/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
03-23 10:51:33.856  17012-17012/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame D/MultiMazed﹕ onCreateEngineOptions() called
03-23 10:51:33.881  17012-17012/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
03-23 10:51:33.896  17012-17012/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame W/PopupManager﹕ You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view which may not work properly in future versions of the API. Use setViewForPopups() to set your content view.
03-23 10:51:33.906  17012-17012/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzg
03-23 10:51:33.906  17012-17012/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 515: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
03-23 10:51:33.906  17012-17012/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
03-23 10:51:33.971  17012-17012/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
03-23 10:51:33.976  17012-17012/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
03-23 10:51:33.981  17012-17012/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
03-23 10:51:33.981  17012-17012/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame E/﹕ Device driver API match
    Device driver API version: 23
    User space API version: 23
03-23 10:51:33.981  17012-17012/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame E/﹕ mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Mon Feb 10 15:44:10 KST 2014
03-23 10:51:34.036  17012-17012/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-23 10:51:34.141  17012-17026/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame D/MultiMazed﹕ onPopulateScene() called
03-23 10:51:34.141  17012-17026/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame D/MultiMazed﹕ onCreateScene() called
03-23 10:51:34.141  17012-17026/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame D/MultiMazed﹕ onCreateResources() called
03-23 10:51:34.336  17012-17012/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-23 10:51:34.336  17012-17012/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d0dc08)
03-23 10:51:34.336  17012-17012/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame, PID: 17012
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk$zza.zzi(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk$zzc.zzjg(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-23 10:51:34.416  17012-17026/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1537K, 32% free 5498K/8056K, paused 3ms+8ms, total 74ms
03-23 10:51:34.481  17012-17026/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 40K, 32% free 5494K/8056K, paused 6ms+3ms, total 50ms
03-23 10:56:34.371  17012-17012/com.tdt4240.a19.mazegame I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 17012 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I fairly new to Android Studios and its use of gradle files. may this be a gradle issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when the app id is incorrect or at the wrong spot. For me I had to change my manifest from:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="000000000000" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

to actually referencing it in the `string.xml` file. So it changed to this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

And then I put my app id in the strings class. I don't know why this was the case but that is what fixed it for me.